# lxml.etree insert elements into element.text

Tags: xml, python-2.7, lxml, elementtree

I have strings that have empty xml elements in them, like this:

```
>>> s = """fizz buzz <pb n="44"/> bananas"""
```

These strings have been assigned to xml elements using the `etree.SubElement` method:

```
>>> from lxml import etree as et
>>> root = et.Element('root')
>>> txt = et.SubElement(root, 'text')
>>> txt.text = s
>>> et.dump(root)
<root>
  <text>fizz buzz &lt;pb n="44"/&gt; bananas</text>
</root>
```

Fiddling about with `re.split()` and etree's `text` and `tail` I can insert a subelement `<pb n="44"/>` where I want it in `txt.text`; however, sometimes I've got multiple occurrences of the `<pb/>` element in the string, which complicates matters:

`>>> s1 = """foo bar <pb n="42"/> parrots like <pb n="43"/> eggs and spam"""`

Is there a straightforward way to insert such elements where they belong in an existing element's `text` without fiddling around too much with `text` and `tail`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make your input string a well-formed XML document (with `text` as the root element) and parse that into an Element object using `fromstring()`. Then append it to the parent.

```
from lxml import etree as et

s1 = """foo bar <pb n="42"/> parrots like <pb n="43"/> eggs and spam"""
s2 = "<text>{0}</text>".format(s1)

text = et.fromstring(s2)
root = et.Element('root')
root.append(text)

et.dump(root)
```

Output:

```
<root>
 <text>foo bar <pb n="42"/> parrots like <pb n="43"/> eggs and spam</text>
</root>
```

Comment: Doh! I danced around that for the longest time. `et.fromstring()` makes it easy. Thanks for taking the trouble to point out what should have been obvious.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help!