# lxml: Including a string (which may include a xml snippet) in a etree.SubElement

Tags: python, xml, lxml, code-snippets

I am writing a XML file with lxml. At a given moment, I have to "paste" the content of a string variable as then "text" of the element. The string may be plain text or contain an arbitrary number valid xml tags (nested, of course) and it is assumed it will be properly tagged.

```
from lxml import etree as ET

snippet = "This is a <b product="man">text</b><b product="aps">test</b> or a list <ul><li>1</li><li>2</li></ul> and should work"

tree = ET.Element('topic')
section = ET.SubElement(tree, 'section')
section.text = <xml converted snippet>
```

I do know that *section.text* is not the way for inserting it, as then snippet converts to something like:

```
This is a &lt;b product="man"&gt;text&lt;/b&gt;...
```

which is not what I need. This is what I want to obtain instead (approximately)(:

```
<topic>
<section>This is a <b product="man">text</b><b product="aps">test</b> 
    or a list 
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
    </ul> 
    and should work
</section>
</topic>
```

I have tried using *ET.fromstring(snippet)* but it fails if it finds nested xml or more than a single element.

Any hint on how to solve it?

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/31951889/407651 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/53332815/407651

Comment: I could not find these entries! They absolutely solve my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> new_snippet = '<section>' + snippet + '</section>'
>>> section = ET.fromstring(new_snippet)
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but what to do with the section thing afterwards?

Comment: tree.insert(0, section) perhaps!